# How to configure BIND to allow RFC2136-style updates for 1 host for Dynamic DNS?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, pfsense, dyndns

I am using Debian on a VPS with static IP and my home network behind PPP with dynamic IP. My pfSense router/firewall shall update my host `home.mydomain.tld` via RFC2136 style updates.

After lots of reading through different tutorials I still have no clue how to setup this up correctly. There are some hosts in my zone file and I want to allow updates with a secret key *for only 1 host*.

Debian automatically creates the file `/etc/bind/rndc.key`. I'd like to use a 2nd key and keep this key for local updates which my change all zones.

How to configure BIND to allow this?

Overview over DynDNS config in pfSense: http://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Dynamic_DNS#2.0_Behavior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got it working today with the help of [this website](https://web.archive.org/web/20131021052013/http://www.shakabuku.org/writing/dyndns.html/)  which I had just found.